# What is the advantage of using Element Buffer Objects, if any?

Tags: opengl, rendering, graphics

I'm following the amazing LearnOpenGL tutorials and noticed that Element Buffer Objects, which were mentioned and used in the Hello Triangle chapter, never appear again. So my question is, **is using Element Buffer Objects good practice and/or does it provide a performance advantage over just specifying the data for each Vertex manually?** I'm very curious about this, and any information would be helpful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: are you talking about `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`?
Those are buffers that contain vertex **indices**. They are very important for indexed drawing.

Comment: @Raildex Yeah, I should probably edit my post to specify what I actually mean.

Comment: Yes, you should. Do that.

Answer (score 0):

EBOs are memory efficient. i.e: It takes you 8 floats to define a basic square instead of 12. For 2D games you could get away with VBOs only, however, the efficiency becomes apparent in 3D where you have 100,000ths polygons to render each frame.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the advice and link! I don't think documentation is necessary in this case though. It's simple stuff :D. If there is more to add to my answer, I appreciate another set of eyes!